# hiding port number through .htaccess node.js express

Tags: javascript, node.js, .htaccess

I am running two node servers on my website. 1 is a socket.io server for live streaming data on the main site and the other is streaming JSON data to a sub-domain api.site.com.

my main node is running on port 8001 and the second is running on 8080. I have been able to hide the port number for the first one in .htaccess using

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 8001
```

but am struggling to hide the `8080` port.

If I add in `RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 8080` and go to my api location `api.site.com/prices/all` I get 404 not found error and if I go to `api.site.com:8080/prices/all` everything still works.

How can I hide the port so `api.site.com/prices/all` works?

This is also slightly linked to my other question: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36960291/node-js-express-handling-other-get-tries) where I want to deny other .get attempts so `api.site.com/price` wont work.

Comment: "I have been able to hide the port number for the first one in .htaccess using" --- that's unlikely, `RewriteCond` is just a condition to match, it does not rewrite anything.

Comment: Check for how to configure apache as a reverse proxy to know how to solve the problem properly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rewrite rule to hide port from URL of Rails server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11330552/rewrite-rule-to-hide-port-from-url-of-rails-server)

Answer (score 2):

You can put your config directly in the domain.conf folder the following works for me every time.  Port here is 8888 change customise that and the domain to your settings.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mydomain.foobar
    ServerAlias mydomain.foobar

    ServerAdmin info@lakes.world
    DocumentRoot /path/to/mydomain.foobar/httpdocs

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPass / http://mydomain.foobar:8888/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://mydomain.foobar:8888/
</VirtualHost>
```